# No puedo enviar ni recibir correos electrónicos; aparece un error con el servidor de SnappyMail. ¿Cuál podría ser el problema?

Tags: email

"Recibo el mensaje de error 'no puedo conectarme al servidor' al hacer clic en 'enviar' un correo electrónico en SnappyMail. Además, no puedo recibir correos electrónicos de nadie ni enviarlos a nadie, ya sea a una dirección de Gmail o a mis propias direcciones de dominio. ¿Cuál podría ser el problema aquí?"  trabajo con Cyberpanel y mi DNS esta en Cloudflare

[image: Envio captura del error]

Comment: ¿Qué hay en `index.php`? ¿Revisaste el log de errores de tu servidor? ¿Por qué pusiste la etiqueta `javamail`?

Comment: Si, igual no funciona nada, aqui no brindan ayuda.